# C#'s Convert.ToInt32(3) converts to 51

Tags: c#

When creating a program that takes a number (like 1253) and turns it into 125^3, I get an odd error where converting a string won't seem to work. Here is my code:

```
        string example = "1253";

        // grab all but the last character
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(example.Substring(0, example.Length - 1));
        Console.WriteLine(num);

        // grab the last character
        //int pow = Convert.ToInt32(example.Substring(example.Length - 1));
        int pow = Convert.ToInt32(example[example.Length - 1]);
        Console.WriteLine(pow);

        // output num to the power of pow
        Console.WriteLine(Math.Pow(num, pow));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

The first initialization of the variable pow works correctly but the second one (not commented out) does not for some reason. The different ways of grabbing the last character of a string work, but for some reason with the first "3" will convert to 3, but for the latter "3" will convert to 51.

Here is the output when using the commented initialization of pow:
125
3
1953125

Here is the output when using the uncommented initialization of pow:
125
51
8.75811540203011E+106

I'm fairly new to C# so any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The ASCII code for the '3' character is 51... ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you use an indexer on a string: `example[example.Length - 1]` you are returned a `char` of value `'3'` (*not a string `"3"`*).

This means a different overload of [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx) is called with a `char` as the parameter. The conversion applied to a `char` is completely different to that which is applied to a `string`.

> *char* : Converts the value of the specified Unicode character to the equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

as opposed to

> *string*: Converts the specified string representation of a number to an equivalent 32-bit signed integer.

If you take a [peek at a Unicode table](https://unicode-table.com/en/#0033), you'll see that `'3'` has a value of hex 33, or 51.

You might have better luck with `example[example.Length - 1].ToString()`.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Stack Overflow makes me wait 10 minutes to accept an answer but once it allows me I'll make sure to.

Thanks again!

Comment: The documentation helps answer the question but is a little sloppy in this case. `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which encode a Unicode codepoint. The remarks finally give an accurate description: [The `ToInt32(Char)` method returns a 32-bit signed integer that represents the UTF-16 encoded code unit of the value argument. If `value` is not a low surrogate or a high surrogate, this return value also represents the Unicode code point of value.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ww9t2871(v=vs.110).aspx) It is "codepoint" that corresponds best with "character."

Comment: or simply `int pow = example[example.Length - 1] - '0'` without converting string to int. @MuadhGhuneim

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a character into Convert.ToInt32() it will convert it into its ASCII value. That's why your 3 is becoming 51.

Comment: Incorrect. `Convert.ToInt32(char)` : "*Converts the value of the specified **Unicode** character to the equivalent 32-bit signed integer.*".